# Not able to retrieve array from cookie on page load after url rewritting in htaccess using php

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /roots_web/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^contact-us.html/$ contact-us.php
RewriteRule ^contact-us.html$ contact-us.php
```

I'm setting the cookie with:

```
 setcookie("reports_cookie[".$report_id."][report]", $report_id);
```

and when I go to other page and check

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['reports_cookie']) && count($_COOKIE['reports_cookie'])>0)
{
}
```

it is not evaluating this condition as true.

Comment: Please add a description to your question, not only code. What is it you actually ask?

Comment: i am setting a cookie in one page which i use on two pages. That is working fine earlier . But after i rewrite the urls in ht accesss file i am unable to get cookies on other page. that shows cookies is not set.

Comment: That's not enough debugging or sufficient to infer this behaviour from. Show how you invoke [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) in the first page, what properties (domain, path, expiration time) your browser stored it with, or some devtools network HTTP  request inspection.

Comment: setcookie("reports_cookie[".$report_id."][report]", $report_id);

Comment: Please do not place additional information in comments to your question. Instead _edit_ your question. Your own interest is to have the question as easy to read and understand as possible, so that you get good and helpful replies. There  is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it!_

Comment: Can you please post any relevant information in your question and _not_ the comments? So people don't have to wade through the comments to know what the actual problem is. Thanks

Comment: Properly specify the _path_ your cookie is supposed to be valid for in your setcookie call. Otherwise it will only be valid under the current path the script setting this cookie was called under. And with `contact-us.html/` vs `contact-us.html` that can make all the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure

```
setcookie("reports_cookie[".$report_id."][report]", $report_id, time()+3600,"/");
```

is used BEFORE any output is done to the browser.

for example

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>
      hello world
    </title>
 </head>
 <?php
   setcookie("reports_cookie[".$report_id."][report]", $report_id, time()+3600,"/");
 ?>
</html>
```

will make it fail because the html output will be sent before the cookie header.

Cookies are set and read by so called [header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) fields. These need to be sent before any output.

Even a  space before the opening php tag can make it fail. even if that space in a file you're "including" before calling the setcookie function.

```
 <?php setcookie("reports_cookie[".$report_id."][report]", $report_id, time()+3600,"/");
^-- a space making your cookies fail
```

If you don't see a space, you might have a UTF8 BOM field at the start of your php document. Recommended is to set your text editor to another text encoding like ANSI to be able to edit UTF8 BOM so you can remove it and then save it and revert back to UTF8 without BOM.

Also, make sure you set your [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on your entire domain. If you fail to specify that then the cookie can only be read on the page that it was set by.

Also remember to set an expiry time, in this case I set a time of 5 minutes after which the cookie will expire.

```
 setcookie("reports_cookie[".$report_id."][report]", $report_id, time()+3600,"/");
```

Also, please think about why you are storing the report ID as an array key and a value...